# tomcat, jvm, monitoring, restarting

Tags: tomcat6

I have a web application running as a jar, I need a automated way to restart this jvm with a reboot/crash.

What are you guys using for this? I am running ubuntu 10.04 lts .  (Examples would be great)

Thanks

Comment: During a server reboot/crash or when the jvm crashes?

Comment: both would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Poor man's solution:

Make your Server create a proper pid file.

Create a bash script, that checks if a process with the pid number exists and if it doesn't starts it.

Then make a cron job that runs this bash script every minute.

(If it's running under Windows, substitute bash with batch script and cron job with an at job)